# user can access admin page using session in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a database with table users. on users table i have a username with value "corny" and username="admin".

on my user.php i have this code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

on my admin.php i have this session

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    if($_SESSION['username'] != "gft-admin"){
        header('location: index.php');
    }
}
```

So my problem is that from users.php I can access admin.php. What should I do to avoid users.php to access admin.php if user is not equal to  'admin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current logic is saying:

```
IF there is no username
  THEN if the username is not gft-admin
    THEN REDIRECT
```

But what you want to say is:

```
IF there is no username
OR if the username is not gft-admin
    THEN redirect
```

Which you would express like:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['username'] != "gft-admin"){
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `!` in the second piece of code and add an else statement for when there is no `$_SESSION['username']` set.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ //remove here
    if($_SESSION['username'] != "gft-admin"){
        header('location: index.php');
    }
} else {
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: still the same i can access when i trype to browser admin.php

Comment: @akirayuki Updated the answer, try again with the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you bypass your admin `if` block entirely when a session is already set. I think you just need to remove the `!` mark.

Comment: still the same i can access when i trype to browser admin.php

Comment: @akirayuki  try clearing your browser/session cache first.